# Is there a generic type for UIMA annotation features?

Tags: java, uima

Is there a generic type, similar to `Object` in Java, that would allow values of different types to be set to it?

```xml
<typeDescription>
    <name>com.example.Annotation</name>
    <description></description>
    <supertypeName>uima.tcas.Annotation</supertypeName>
    <features>
        <featureDescription>
            <name>exampleFeature</name>
            <description>An example feature</description>
            <rangeTypeName>uima.cas.Generic</rangeTypeName>
        </featureDescription>
    </features>
</typeDescription>
```

I have tried putting the following in `<rangeTypeName>`:

- **java.lang.Object** and **Object** This doesn't work and I get the following message when trying to generate the code using JCasGen:

  JCasGen Warning: ****** Resource Initialization Error occurred while instantiating the CAS type system. Continuing, but may generate incorrectly.  Caused by 'Undefined type "Object", referenced in feature "exampleFeature" declared on type "com.example.Annotation".
- **uima.cas.TOP** This generates the code but then gives an error when I try to call the `setExampleField()` method by passing it an `int` or `String` as it cannot convert them to the TOP type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **uima.cas.TOP** is the **Object**-equivalent type of UIMA. But it is slightly different from what you would expect. UIMA operates with two concepts: 1) **FeatureStructure**, 2) **primitive types** (int, boolean, etc. and String!). If you set the range of a feature to TOP, it can accept any kind of feature structure (i.e. anything that inherits from TOP), but not any of the primitive types - no auto-boxing here. If you set the range to a primitive type, then it will only accept that type.

A work-around could be to define custom types , e.g. FSInt, FSString, FSBoolean which inherit from TOP and which would have a "value" feature of the respective type (int, String, boolean). You could then set the value in that FS and assign it to a feature with range TOP.

*Note: I am currently a committer on the Apache UIMA project.*