# UIMA custom type with custom feature type range

Tags: java, eclipse, uima

I'm working on a UIMA project with Eclipse. The project is created as a Maven project and thus has the folder `src/main/resources` which I use for my type definitions (in the subfolder `desc`).

Further project information:

- Group Id: com.example
- Artifact Id: myproject

I'm trying to create a custom annotation type which also has a feature with a custom range using the "Component Descriptor Editor".
Instead of choosing a standard range type from the namespace `uima.cas`or `uima.tcas` I want the feature to be an object of the class `CustomRangeType` in my package `data`.

[image: Component Descriptor Editor with error message]

This image depicts the Component Descriptor Editor with my inputs and the corresponding error message:

> RangeType 'com.example.myproject.data.CustomRangeType' is unknown. If this is intended, please define it first.

I understand the first sentence (the problem is quite obvious). However, I'm puzzled by the second sentence... I have searched how to "define" a custom range, but haven't been successful. Due to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895340/3867423), I assume that it is in fact possible to define a custom range type. Unfortunately, I don't know how and couldn't find an answer as well.

I would be very thankful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you define a feature with a range of a given type, you need to define that type.

To do this:

- press the *Add type* button
- in type name enter the name of the type you wish to use as the range, e.g. "com.example.myproject.data.CustomRangeType"
- choose an appropriate supertype or leave the default
- press OK

After that, go back to the adding your feature. You should also now be able to find your type by pressing *browse* and entering *CustomRangeType*.

Disclosure: *Apache UIMA project member*

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I guess I had a terrible missunderstanding of what feature type ranges are. 
So every feature type range has to be a UIMA type itself (either a predefined or a cusom one). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You cannot use arbitrary Java types as feature ranges - they must all be types known to UIMA.